# how can i add all elements of a struct array into another struct array?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I am using matlab and trying to take struct arrays, and add them together to make a "super-struct array". Here are my two struct arrays:

```
>> ion_seed

ion_seed = 

285x1 struct array with fields:
    Header
    Sequence

>> lig_seed

lig_seed = 

44x1 struct array with fields:
    Header
    Sequence
```

my question is how do I add them together. I don't want to concatenate them, but rather insert one into the other.

so I end up with:

```
>>super_struct =

329x1 struct array with fields:
        Header
        Sequence
```

Is this even possible? I have only seen people concatenate struct arrays.

thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just vertically concatenate them like any other array

```
super_struct = [ion_seed; lig_seed];
```